# Dividing DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

**Data:**

```
year    month   is_p    segment x       y
2018    JAN     Y       de      200     500
2018    JAN     N       de      100     200
2018    JAN     N       de      500     500
2018    JAN     Y       de      1000    500
```

**Expected Output:**

```
year month segment is_p   x     y     %of allocation_x  %of allocation_y                                              
2018 JAN   de      N      600   700          0.333333          0.411765
                   Y     1200  1000          0.666667          0.588235
```

**What I have tried:**
I did the groupby and took the sum of the values for all Y. After taking the sum,  I divided the y contribution by the total sum.

```
df_p=df.groupby([year,month,is_p,segment]).sum() 
# To get the total sum for Y & N for is_p column
df_total=df.groupby([year,month,segment]).sum() 
# To get the total sum per segment.
```

Now, I want to get the percentage of values (column - `x,y`) with respect to `is_p` column. 
If there is any other way, please help with the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your data/code properly (check the help section of the site). I have a feeling we could easily help if we could understand your question better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for this!
First do the groupby on `['year','month','segment']`, then within each group get the sum for x and y with respect to `is_p`. With the sums, then get the percentages for each subcategories

```
d=''' year    month   is_p    segment x       y
2018    JAN     Y       de      200     500
2018    JAN     N       de      100     200
2018    JAN     N       de      500     500
2018    JAN     Y       de      1000    500
2019    JAN     Y       de      200     500
2019    JAN     N       de      100     2000
2019    JAN     N       de      5000     500
2019    JAN     Y       de      1000    500'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(d), sep='\s+') 

def f(x):    
    grouped = x.groupby('is_p').agg(sum)
    for c in grouped.columns:
        grouped['%of allocation'+str(c)] = grouped[c]/grouped[c].sum()
    return grouped

interested_cols =['x','y']
df.groupby(['year','month','segment'])[['is_p']+interested_cols].apply(f)
```

Output:

```
                            x     y  %of allocation_x  %of allocation_y
year month segment is_p                                                
2018 JAN   de      N      600   700          0.333333          0.411765
                   Y     1200  1000          0.666667          0.588235
2019 JAN   de      N     5100  2500          0.809524          0.714286
                   Y     1200  1000          0.190476          0.285714
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked out and it helps. However, let's say there are various measures like x, y, z, r, p , q, s , t. How can I set up the loop for the same.

Comment: Yes, that answer helps.Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918022/forecasting-basis-the-historical-figures

Comment: Kindly review the above link also so as to guide as this pertains to the same problem. any help would be appreciated.