# Forecasting basis the historical figures

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting

I want to forecast the allocations basis the historical figures.

Manual Input provided by the user:

```
year    month     x          y          z          k
2018    JAN  9,267,581   627,129     254,110     14,980 
2018    FEB  7,771,691   738,041     217,027     17,363
```

Output from Historical figures:

```
year  month segment pg  is_p    x   y   z   k
2018    JAN A   p   Y   600 600 600 600
2018    JAN A   p   N   200 200 200 200
2018    JAN B   r   Y   400 400 400 400
2018    JAN A   r   Y   400 400 400 400
2018    JAN A   r   N   400 400 400 400
2018    JAN B   r   N   300 300 300 300
2018    JAN C   s   Y   200 200 200 200
2018    JAN C   s   N   10  10  10  10
2018    JAN C   t   Y   11  11  11  11
2018    JAN C   t   N   12  12  12  12
2018    FEB A   p   Y   789 789 789 789
2018    FEB A   p   N   2093874 2093874 2093874 2093874
```

I have tried calculating the allocation of `is_p` from the total like let say I add certain columns to calculate the %of allocation:

1. `%ofx_segment`= 600+200+400+400/600+200+400+400+400+300+200+10+11+12. This will give me how much x is contributed from segment
   The same goes with y,z,k
2. I multiply the manual input that is 9276581 * `%ofx_segment` to calculate the value of segment_x
3. Then, I calculate `%_pg`. For segment A for Jan 2018, `%_pg`= 600+200/600+200+400+400
4. Then, I multiply the manual input received from Step 2 * %pg received from 3 for 'p' in pg for A segment
5. Then, at last, I will calculate % of is_p, I will calculate % Y or %N
   for p in pg for A in segment % Y is =600/600+200.
6. The value received from Step 5 has to be multiplied to the output received from 4.

---

```
import pandas as pd
first=pd.read_csv('/Users/arork/Downloads/first.csv')
second=pd.read_csv('/Users/arork/Downloads/second.csv')
interested_columns=['x','y','z','k']
second=pd.read_csv('/Users/arork/Downloads/second.csv')
interested_columns=['x','y','z','k']
primeallocation=first.groupby(['year','month','pg','segment'])[['is_p']+interested_columns].apply(f)
segmentallocation=first.groupby(['year','month'])[['segment']+interested_columns].apply(g)
pgallocation=first.groupby(['year','month','segment'])[['pg']+interested_columns].apply(h)
segmentallocation['%of allocation_segment x']
np.array(second)
func = lambda x: x * np.asarray(second['x'])
segmentallocation['%of allocation_segment x'].apply(func)
```

Comment: @AILearning: Kindly review

Comment: Show us what have you tried and whats the error. Do add an expected output as well.

Comment: interested_columns={'x','y','z','p','q','r'}

Comment: I started with getting the allocation for segment_allocation.

Comment: @ AI_Learning- Here, I am unable to figure out how to multiply the percentage of the allocation with the manual input given for x, y, z, k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join those two dataframes to perform multiplication of two columns.

```
merged_df = segmentallocation.merge(second,on=['year','month'],how='left',suffixes=['','_second'])

for c in interested_columns:
        merged_df['allocation'+str(c)] = merged_df['%of allocation'+str(c)] * merged_df[c] 

merged_df


    year    month   segment x   y   z   k   %of allocationx %of allocationy %of allocationz %of allocationk x_second    y_second    z_second    k_second    allocationx allocationy allocationz allocationk
0   2018    FEB A   2094663 2094663 2094663 2094663 1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    7,771,691   738,041 217,027 17,363  2.094663e+06    2.094663e+06    2.094663e+06    2.094663e+06
1   2018    JAN A   1600    1600    1600    1600    0.631662    0.631662    0.631662    0.631662    9,267,581   627,129 254,110 14,980  1.010659e+03    1.010659e+03    1.010659e+03    1.010659e+03
2   2018    JAN B   700 700 700 700 0.276352    0.276352    0.276352    0.276352    9,267,581   627,129 254,110 14,980  1.934465e+02    1.934465e+02    1.934465e+02    1.934465e+02
3   2018    JAN C   233 233 233 233 0.091986    0.091986    0.091986    0.091986    9,267,581   627,129 254,110 14,980  2.143269e+01    2.143269e+01    2.143269e+01    2.143269e+01
```

Comment: You need to define all the terms in your question. what is your function `g`,`h`?

I am giving the answer, just by guess those functions.

Comment: The way, we are grouping on is_p, I want to get the sum for segment and then prime

Comment: Segment is further divided into pg which is further divided into p